# Using IdentityModel.AspNetCore to manage access tokens for use with Google APIs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I found references to using IdentityModel.AspNetCore to manage access tokens here on stackoverflow.  Seems nice in that it handles the access token behind the scenes. But after coding up a test, I realized that I don't understand it in the context of OAuth2.

As I get no hits when googling on using this with, for example, Google's OAuth2-based APIs, I'm thinking that I've barked up the wrong tree. But if I'm wrong and this can be used to manage the token refresh flow, I'd be grateful for some pointers.